# How can I adapt the width of a div according to its content in a flex grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The idea is to give each child div an adaptive width within a parent flex div. I have a few child divs with more content than the others and I don't want the text to overflow the div but for the div to adapt horizontally to contain all the text.

I don't know how to do it, but I need to know how to do it.

You can see a picture of my problem here :

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2hln.png)

and my code :

```
        .reviews_block {
            display: flex;
            width: 2778px;
            transform: translateX(50px);
        }

        .reviews_item {
            min-width: 419px;
            max-height: 95px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .item_wrap {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }


<div class="reviews_block">
    <div class="reviews_item">
        <div class="item_wrap">
            <div class="item_wrap-text">
                <p>*Short text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews_item">
        <div class="item_wrap">
            <div class="item_wrap-text">
                <p>*Short text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to do it, but I need to know how to do it.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code to show the context in your image? It is hard to comment on what you need to change as this code is too minimal.